# Installing Firebase SDK in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pythonanywhere

I am trying to use firebase in PythonAnywhere cloud services.
I have installed firebase-python SDK in the bash console using the commands:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 deploy
```

and then

```
pip install firebase-python
```

I have added the virtual env path in the web app and done all the settings in the WSGI configuration file. But when I import the firebase SDK in my `web app` using `from firebase import firebase`:

I get the error in the console that

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'
```

Comment: How do you run your web app? Your setting on the web app page do not apply to the stuff you do in the cosole.

Comment: @Filip how do I connect the bash console and web app? 
I'm running the web app through web page on the website.

Comment: You don't need to use a console at all to run a web app on PythonAnywhere.  Once it's set up on the "Web" page on the website, it's started and stopped as necessary to serve requests.  If you're getting an error when you visit your site, you should look in the error log for the site -- there's a link on the "Web" page, and the most recent error is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: If, for some reason, you want to run some code in a console in the same environment as the one your website uses, either start the console using the "Start a bash console in this virtualenv" link on the "Web" page, or activate the virtualenv from bash using "workon".

Answer (score 0):

try:
`pip install firebase`
or use the firebase admin SDK:
`pip install firebase-admin`
end:
`import firebase-admin`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too.

By default, Pythonanywhere creates an environment with the last python version (like principal), even when you indicate other. Looking logs errors. The python version it's ok.

[image]

But in console, python --version show 3.9. That is the problem. You could Install packages indicating  the right version, in my case:
python3.8 -m pip install firebase-admin

**And reload**

```
from flask import Flask
import firebase_admin
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'
```